# AG-Grid Sorting wont work properly if there is 'asc' or 'desc' as cell value

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, angular13

While working on my project, I found a strange issue that if a cell have either 'asc' or 'desc' as value, then sorting to that particular AG-Grid column will not work properly.

Screenshot of Issue from Plunker [image: Screenshot of Issue]

Here Sorting 'Country Desc' column in Ascending order shows 'desc' related cells after 'Zimbabwe' but it should show 'desc' related cells after 'Denmark'

[image]

Please go through the plunker URL :
[Click here](https://plnkr.co/edit/oXTEw3x6ztzK2or2?open=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

```js
import {
  HttpClient
} from '@angular/common/http';
import {
  Component
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  ColDef,
  GridReadyEvent
} from 'ag-grid-community';
import 'ag-grid-community/styles/ag-grid.css';
import 'ag-grid-community/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css';
import {
  IOlympicData
} from './interfaces';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<ag-grid-angular
    style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"
    class="ag-theme-alpine"
    [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
    [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef"
    [rowData]="rowData"
    (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
  ></ag-grid-angular>`,
})
export class AppComponent {
  public columnDefs: ColDef[] = [{
      field: 'athlete',
      sort: 'desc'
    },
    {
      field: 'age',
      width: 90
    },
    {
      field: 'countryDesc'
    },
    {
      field: 'year',
      width: 90,
      unSortIcon: true
    },
    {
      field: 'date',
      comparator: dateComparator
    },
    {
      field: 'sport'
    },
    {
      field: 'gold'
    },
    {
      field: 'silver'
    },
    {
      field: 'bronze'
    },
    {
      field: 'total'
    },
  ];
  public defaultColDef: ColDef = {
    width: 170,
    sortable: true,
  };
  public rowData!: IOlympicData[];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  onGridReady(params: GridReadyEvent < IOlympicData > ) {
    this.http
      .get < IOlympicData[] > (
        'https://www.ag-grid.com/example-assets/olympic-winners.json'
      )
      .subscribe((data) => {

        this.rowData = data.map(x => {
          // preparing the data here
          return { ...x,
            countryDesc: x.country === 'Russia' ? 'desc' : x.country
          };
        });
      });
  }
}

function dateComparator(date1: string, date2: string) {
  const date1Number = monthToComparableNumber(date1);
  const date2Number = monthToComparableNumber(date2);
  if (date1Number === null && date2Number === null) {
    return 0;
  }
  if (date1Number === null) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (date2Number === null) {
    return 1;
  }
  return date1Number - date2Number;
}
// eg 29/08/2004 gets converted to 20040829
function monthToComparableNumber(date: string) {
  if (date === undefined || date === null || date.length !== 10) {
    return null;
  }
  const yearNumber = Number.parseInt(date.substring(6, 10));
  const monthNumber = Number.parseInt(date.substring(3, 5));
  const dayNumber = Number.parseInt(date.substring(0, 2));
  return yearNumber * 10000 + monthNumber * 100 + dayNumber;
}
```

Though I would have to think of another way of sorting the data to meet my project deadline but any help on this is really appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps this is happening because of the capitalisation?

Comment: Yeah really, I just tried, making everything in lowercase and then I surprised to see the result, its working fine that way. But in my case the values are coming from the database as it is and don't think it will be good to capitalize the data at client side

Comment: Looks like setting up a custom comparator (that will force lowercase for both values) is the way to go: "Custom sorting is provided at a column level by configuring a comparator on the column definition" https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/row-sorting/#custom-sorting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can utilize [`localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) by adding comparator to your `defaultColDef` like so:

```
  public defaultColDef: ColDef = {
    width: 170,
    sortable: true,
    comparator: (valueA, valueB) => valueA.localeCompare(valueB),
  };
```